# PHP SDK can't access user email from profile

Tags: php, facebook

We are experiencing a strange problem, we have several users using Facebook's authentication in our app, but one of our recent users can't login.

I've debugged the error to be related to the email field not being in the fields from https://graph.facebook.com/me.

We are requesting the following permissions on login:

```
    $params = array(
            'scope' => 'email,publish_stream',
            'redirect_uri' => "$_BASE_URL/$authPage"
    );

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

and for all of our other users we get the email field, we've also looked into the user's settings in his facebook account and our app appears there with the email access request permission.

Any idea about the reason for this (hidden setting in facebook preferences?)

Comment: have you confirmed that the users actually have a confirmed email address on their Facebook accounts? the APi won't return an address for users without a valid address

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue. But finally we figured it out. That user didn't confirmed his email id associated with his facebook account. Facebook can provide you the email id if and only the user had a confirmed one with his account. If you don't have a problem with any other users, this may be the issue.